# Prove if $G$ is an abelian group, then $q(x) = x^2$ defines a homomorphism from $G$ into $G$. Is $q$ ever an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Prove if $G$ is an abelian group, then $q(x) = x^2$ defines a homomorphism from $G$ into $G$. Is $q$ ever an isomorphism?

The first proof was no problem, I'm having trouble with the isomorphism piece though. My book has the following explanation that I don't quite understand:

"In order for $q$ to be an isomorphism, it must be the case that no element other than the identity is its own inverse. $x \in $Ker$(q) \iff q(x) = e \iff x*x = e \iff x^{-1} = x$"

It also has a hint to think about it another way, considering $\Bbb Z_n$ for small values of $n$, which I also can't quite wrap my brain around...

Comment: Can it ever be iso?  Yes, on $\mathbb{Z}_3$ for example.

Comment: As you remark, non-trivial elements of the kernel would have order $2$.  So if $2$ doesn't divide the order of the group then...

Answer (score 2):

$q$ is injective iff $G$ has no element of order $2$.

If $G$ is finite, this happens iff the order of $G$ is odd. In this case, $q$ is an isomorphism.

If $G$ is infinite, $q$ might not be surjective even if it is injective. An example is $G=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

If there was an element other than the identity that is its own inverse, then the homomorphism would send it to the identity (because taking it squared would give you the identity).

Since a homomorphism from a group to itself is an isomorphism only if the identity is the only element in the group that's sent to the identity by the homomorphism, you can't have an element that is its own inverse.

A good example of a group that satisfies this is $\mathbb Z_3$. Generally, notice that the order of the group can't be even (can you see why?)

Comment: Assuming the group is finite....

Comment: @Randall Even if the group is infinite it's still a necessary condition for an isomorphism (though it's not quite enough), so if it's not satisfied you can immediately rule it out as an isomorphism.

Comment: @Randall You're right, changed it accordingly

Comment: @GSofer would you mind explaining why the order of the group can't be even?

Comment: @c87 If the order is even, then consider the function that sends each member of the group to its inverse. Naturally, the identity is mapped to itself, so we have an odd number of members left to map. But this means that another member must be mapped to itself, because you can't pair up everyone that's left (there has to be at least one member that gets paired up to itself). That member is its own inverse and therefor if you take it squared you get the identity, which contradicts the necessary condition for isomorphism.